# Sql cannot create table missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I created the table `employee` and `Salaire`. But I get an error when creating the table `Zone`:

> 00907-0000 missing right parenthesis

Code:

```
Create table Employee 
(
    CodeEmploye int,
    NAS Number (9),
    Nom Varchar(20) not null,
    Prenom Varchar(20) not null,
    NomJeuneFille varchar(20) not null,
    DateNaissance Date,   
    Adresse varchar(100) not null,
    Sexe Char(1),
    Telephone Varchar(14),
    Fonction Varchar(20) not null,
    Service varchar(13) not null,
    Taux Number(6,2) default (0),
    Grade Varchar(2),

    Constraint PK_Employe Primary key (CodeEmployee),
    Constraint NAS_Employe Unique (NAS),
    Constraint Verfi_Sexe Check Sexe IN ('F', 'M'),
    Constraint verif_Service Check Service IN ('adminstratif', 'surveillance', 'medical'),   
    Constraint verfi_Grade Check grade in ('G1', 'G2','G3', 'G4', 'G5')
);

Create Table Salaire
(
    CodeEmployee int, 
    Mois int,     
    Salaire Number(11,2) default (0),

    Constraint PK__Salaire Primary key (CodeEmployee, Mois),
    Constraint verif_Mois Check Mois between 1 and 12,
    Constraint FK_Salaire_Employe Foreign Key (CodeEmploye) references Employee(CodeEmployee) 
);

Create Table Zone
(
    CodeZone int,
    NomZone Varchar(20), not null 
    ChefZone Varchar(20),     

    Constraint PK_Zone Primary Key (CodeZone),
    Constraint FK_Zone_Employee Foreign Key (ChefZone) references Employee(Taux, Grade) On delete set null on update cascade
```

Comment: you missed  closing  ) at the end of Create Table Zone(

Comment: DO NOT USE VARCHAR - it's reserved, use VARCHAR2 in Oracle

Comment: The only thing unusual about the `Zone` table is this line: `NomZone Varchar(20), not null ` - don't put a comma between your datatype and the `not null` .....

Answer (score 0):

you need to add parenthesis after check

```
Create table Employe (
CodeEmploye int,
NAS Number (9),
Nom Varchar(20) not null,
Prenom Varchar(20) not null,
NomJeuneFille varchar(20) not null,
DateNaissance Date,   
Adresse varchar(100) not null,
Sexe Char(1),
Telephone Varchar(14),
Fonction Varchar(20) not null,
Service varchar(30) not null,
Taux Number(6,2) default 0,
Grade Varchar(2),
Constraint PK_Employe Primary key (CodeEmploye),
CONSTRAINT NAS_Employe Unique  (NAS),
Constraint Verfi_Sexe Check (Sexe IN ('F', 'M')),
Constraint verif_Service Check ( Service IN ('adminstratif', 'surveillance', 'medical')),   
Constraint verfi_Grade Check (grade in ('G1', 'G2','G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
);

Create Table Salaire(
CodeEmploye int, 
Mois int,     
Salaire Number(11,2) default (0),
Constraint PK__Salaire Primary key (CodeEmploye, Mois),
Constraint verif_Mois Check (Mois between 1 and 12),
Constraint FK_Salaire_Employe Foreign Key (CodeEmploye) references Employe(CodeEmploye));
```

and for 3rd table you need to correct your foregin key definition

Comment: more than that, there's no ON UPDATE clause for a FK, only ON DELETE